# uncaught exit normal && crash affecting parent process Elixir

Tags: elixir

As a result of the GraphQL request, some DB operations are being done within the Phoenix application, and during those operations, I started a gen server this way,

```
  def start_fingerprint_fraud_check(customer_identity) do
    id = process_name("customer_identity-" <> "#{customer_identity.id}")

    General.Supervisor.start_child(NectarineCredit.Risk.IdentityCheck, %{
      id: id,
      ref: nil,
      type: :worker
    })
    |> case do
      {:ok, _pid} ->
        GenServer.call(id, {:validate_customer_identity_fraud, customer_identity})

      {:error, {:already_started, _pid}} ->
        Logger.debug(
          "Identity fraud check is already running for this customer: #{
            customer_identity.customer_id
          }"
        )

        GenServer.call(id, {:validate_customer_identity_fraud, customer_identity})
    end
  end
```

and In gen server.

```
defmodule NectarineCredit.Risk.IdentityCheck do
  @moduledoc false

  use GenServer, restart: :temporary

  require Logger

  def start_link(opts) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: opts.id)
  end

  def init(opts) do
    {:ok, opts}
  end

  def handle_call(
        {:validate_customer_identity_fraud, _customer_identity},
        _from,
        %{ref: ref} = state
      )
      when is_reference(ref) do
    {:reply, :ok, state}
  end

  def handle_call(
        {:validate_customer_identity_fraud, customer_identity},
        _from,
        %{ref: nil} = state
      ) do
    task =
      Task.Supervisor.async_nolink(NectarineCredit.TaskSupervisor, fn ->
        #stuff
      end)

    # We return :ok and the server will continue running
    {:reply, :ok, %{state | ref: task.ref}}
  end

  # The task completed successfully
  def handle_info({ref, answer}, %{ref: ref} = state) do
    Process.demonitor(ref, [:flush])
    {:stop, :normal, %{state | ref: nil}}
  end

  # The task failed
  def handle_info({:DOWN, ref, :process, _pid, reason}, %{ref: ref} = state) do
    {:stop, :shutdown, %{state | ref: nil}}
  end

  def terminate(exit_state, _state) do
    Logger.debug("Process went down as #{exit_state}")
  end
end
```

Problems:

1. when the task `Task.Supervisor.async_nolink` done all the work and gen server went down as normal, I am getting this error,

   Uncaught exit - {:normal, {GenServer, :call, [:"customer_identity-dbdd5d5c-a827-4b75-91cd-dade07b39c8e", {:validate_customer_identity_fraud, %NectarineCredit.Identities{somedata}}, 5000]}}
2. This process should be isolated, no matter if it fails It should not disturb another process, but when this Uncaught exit happens, it gives 500 status to the GrapQL call as well in which its happening. To my understanding, it should be isolated and run/crash in its own space.

any help would be great.

Comment: The code provided is a bit confusing: the error message contains a `validate_customer_identity_fraud`. In the GenServer there are two handlers: `validate_customer_identity_fraud` and `validate_vendor_identity_fraud`. And on GraphQL layer you send a `validate_vendor_identity_fraud` message to the GenServer. That means there should be no errors with `validate_customer_identity_fraud` type as it's not called!


I suppose the provided code is not fully described or there is a mistake in it

Comment: no there was no mistake, I corrected the question and changed genserver call in first block